# Find parameters such that cumulative geometric distribution function equals cumulative exponential distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm given three random variables $X,Y,Z$ with the following distributions: $X$~$Exp(\lambda)$ (exponential distribution), $Y$~$Geom(p)$ (geometric distribution), $Z$~$Y + a, a \in \mathbb{R}$. How can I find $a, p$ depending on $\lambda$ such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$ the cumulative exponential distribution function $F^X(k)$ equals $F^Z(k)$?

How I tried to solve the problem:

$X$~$Exp(\lambda) \Rightarrow F^X(k) = \begin{cases}
0, k \leq 0\\
1 - e^{-\lambda k}, k > 0\\
\end{cases}$

$Y$~$Geom(p) \Rightarrow F^Y(k) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k}P(Y = i) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k} p(1 - p)^i = p\frac{1 - (1 - p)^{k + 1}}{1 - (1 - p)} = 1 - (1 - p)^{k + 1}$.

My guess now is that $Z$ is geometrically distributed as well. If I denote $k' := k + a$, then $P(Z = k') = p(1 - p)^{k + a}$. The cumulated geometric function then becomes:
$ F^Z(k) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k}P(Z = i) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k} p(1 - p)^{i + a} = p(1 - p)^{a}\frac{1 - (1 - p)^{k + 1}}{1 - (1 - p)} = (1 - p)^{a}(1 - (1 - p)^{k + 1})$.

This now brings me nowhere, because I could write $a:= 0\cdot \lambda$ but I cannot find anything for $p$. How can I the approach this problem? Or what am I doing here wrong?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The set of values of $Z$ are $\left\{a + k : k\ge 0\right\}$. You are looking for $p$ and $a$ such that for every $k\ge 0$ \begin{align}
F^{X}\left(a+k\right) &= F^{Z}(a+k)
\end{align}

this is equivalent to have \begin{align}
F^X(a+k) &= F^Y(k)\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad 1 - e^{-\lambda (a + k)} &= 1  - (1-p)^{k}\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad e^{-\lambda k}e^{-\lambda a} &= (1-p)^{k}\\
\end{align}

So $e^{-\lambda a} = 1$ and $e^{-\lambda} = 1-p$. Which implies $a = 0$ and $p = 1-e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But why $F^X(a + k)$ ? And how is  $F^X(a + k) = F^Z(a + k)$ equivalent to  $F^X(a + k) = F^Y(k)$? What is the cumulative distribution function of $Z$?

Comment: From what I understand you want the same value in $F^X$ and $F^Z$ as it stated in the question.

Comment: Yes! But $F^X, F^Z$ are both depended on $k$ only(and not $a + k$. Why $F^X(a + k)$ instead of $F^X(k)$? And how is $F^Z(a + k) = F^Y(k)?$. Or maybe I didn't understand what $Y + a$ actually means. I thought of the geometric distribution as of a table: in the first row values of $i$ from 0 to a certain $n$, in the second row the probability $P(Y = i) := p(1 - p)^i$. If $Z$ ~ $Y + a$ then I thought I'd have the same table as described before, just with an $a$ added to every $i$.The probability then becomes $p(1 - p)^{i + a}$. Then $Z$ would also be geometrically distributed.